# How can I pass the results with the specific ids of the user?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a school app and I want to track grades and attendance in it but I run into a problem when passing the grade and the id side to side and I have a working code of the attendance it's working perfectly and I attached the file for the [Attendance](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19LI2n1PVyi0ES0PvaRvvaIpg4gFziPTB/view?usp=sharing) but the problem is with grades I can't use the same way for the `textfeild` as the `switch`.And this is the file for [Grade](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bqCeqZe3X_TnWhfddVoYRXaA4AUqoie4/view?usp=sharing) filling.

The problem is with the `TextFeild` widget

```
child: TextField(
                                          // controller: resultController,
                                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                          onSubmitted: (grade) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              resultController.text = grade;
                                            });
                                            onResultChanged(
                                                students[index].data()["id"],
                                                grade);
                                          },
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                            labelText: 'Result',
                                          ),
                                        ),
```

How can I manage it in the same manner as the switch in the attendance class?

The attendance class `switch` widget

```
Switch(
                                  value: switchStates[
                                      students[index].data()["id"]],
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      stateofvalue = value;
                                    });
                                    onSwitchChanged(
                                        students[index].data()["id"], value);
                                  },
                                  activeColor: Color(0xff2fbd9f),
                                ),
```

Edited!!
This is how I want to save to firestore
[image]
And this is what the ui looks like
[image]

Comment: Can you provide more info on what your are trying to do. Perhaps use screen shots to make it clear.

Comment: I want to pass the text field value as the switch state

Comment: You already said that but it’s not clear. Switch used bool text is string. Please explain the goal better. Use images if needed.

Comment: I agree, I do not fully understand what you're attempting or what is the issue. Could you maybe reformulate the question or provide more information on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Roger i have added more information on the post can you please help me out

Comment: @Kent i have added more information on the post can you please help me out